# C++ Hash Table - How is collision for unordered_map with custom data type as keys resolved?

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map, user-defined-types, hash-collision

I have defined a class called `Point` which is to be used as a key inside an `unordered_map`. So, I have provided an `operator==` function inside the class and I have also provided a `template specialization` for `std::hash`. Based on my research, these are the two things I found necessary. The relevant code is as shown:

```
class Point
{
    int x_cord = {0};
    int y_cord = {0};
public:
    Point()
    {

    }
    Point(int x, int y):x_cord{x}, y_cord{y}
    {

    }
    int x() const
    {
        return x_cord;
    }
    int y() const
    {
        return y_cord;
    }
    bool operator==(const Point& pt) const
    {
        return (x_cord == pt.x() && y_cord == pt.y());
    }
};

namespace std
{
    template<>
    class hash<Point>
    {
    public:
        size_t operator()(const Point& pt) const
        {
            return (std::hash<int>{}(pt.x()) ^ std::hash<int>{}(pt.y()));
        }
    };
}

// Inside some function
std::unordered_map<Point, bool> visited;
```

The program compiled and gave the correct results in the cases that I tested. However, I am not convinced if this is enough when using a user-defined class as key. How does the `unordered_map` know how to resolve collision in this case? Do I need to add anything to resolve collision?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a terrible hash function. But it is legal, so your implementation will work.

The rule (and really the only rule) for Hash and Equals is:

- if `a == b`, then `std::hash<value_type>(a) == std::hash<value_type>(b)`.

(It's also important that both Hash and Equals always produce the same value for the same arguments. I used to think that went without saying, but I've seen several SO questions where unordered_map produced unexpected results precisely because one or both of these functions depended on some external value.)

That would be satisfied by a hash function which always returned 42, in which case the map would get pretty slow as it filled up. But other than the speed issue, the code would work.

`std::unordered_map` uses a [chained hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining), not an open-addressed hash. All entries with the same hash value are placed in the same bucket, which is a linked list. So low-quality hashes do not distribute entries very well among the buckets.

It's clear that your hash gives `{x, y}` and `{y, x}` the same hash value. More seriously, any collection of points in a small rectangle will share the same small number of different hash values, because the high-order bits of the hash values will all be the same.

Comment: How can I select a better hash function? Does something like `x_cord * 10 + y_cord` work? Is it all about finding a unique value of `size_t` type?

Comment: I'd multiply by a larger number, probably a prime (or at least not an even number). You don't need to find a unique number; just make sure the values are well-distributed. (Remember to cast both `x_cord` and `y_cord` to `unsigned` to avoid potential integer overflow UB.)

Comment: What is the reasoning behind using a prime or odd number?

Comment: If you use an even number, `x_cord` doesn't affect the low-order bit of the hash because the product is always even.

Comment: Thank you. I have changed the return statement to `std::hash<int>{}(pt.x()) * 17 + std::hash<int>{}(pt.y())`

Answer (score 3):

[Knowing that `Point` is intended to store coordinates within an image](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/202624/c-flood-fill-using-unordered-map-which-has-user-defined-type-as-key/202972#202972), the best hash function here is:

```
pt.x() + pt.y() * width
```

where `width` is the width of the image.

Considering that `x` is a value in the range `[0, width-1]`, the above hash function produces a unique number for any valid value of `pt`. No collisions are possible.

Note that this hash value corresponds to the linear index for the point `pt` if you store the image as a single memory block. That is, given `y` is also in a limited range (`[0, height-1]`), all hash values generated are within the range `[0, width* height-1]`, and all integers in that range can be generated. Thus, consider replacing your hash table with a simple array (i.e. an image). An image is the best data structure to map a pixel location to a value.